# Androidのアプリ名を日本語にしたい

Tags: android, cordova

下記、２通りの方法を試しましたが、Android版でアプリ名を日本語にできませんでした。

- 方法１

下記のサイトに書かれていることを実施し、ビルドする際にplatformsのフォルダを追加する。

https://designsupply-web.com/knowledgeside/1755/

- 方法２

cordova-custom-configプラグインの機能を使う。

具体的には、cordova-custom-configプラグインを追加し、
下記をconfig.xmlファイルに追記する。

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-manifest/application/activity/@android:label" value="サンプルアプリ名前" />
</platform>
```

ちなみにですが、iOSの方は
cordova-custom-configプラグインを追加し、
下記をconfig.xmlファイルに追記すれば
アプリ名を日本語にできました。

```
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="CFBundleDisplayName">
        <string>サンプルアプリ名前</string>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

Android版でアプリ名を日本語にする方法をご存知の方、
方法を教えて頂けますでしょうか。

---

**バージョン**
Phonegap Buiid : 7.1.0
cordova-custom-config : 5.0.2
Android : 5.0.1

Answer (score 2):

私が使用しているサードパーティプラグインの紹介になりますが、下記のプラグインを使用することで両OSとも対応できます。

https://github.com/kelvinhokk/cordova-plugin-localization-strings

```
// translations/app/ja.json
{
  "config_ios" : {
    "CFBundleDisplayName": "サンプルアプリ名前",
    "CFBundleName": "サンプルアプリ名前"
  },
  "config_android" : {
    "app_name": "サンプルアプリ名前"
  }
}
```

Android、iOSともに各プロジェクトでローカライゼーションファイルを作成することでアプリ名の表示を変更することができます。上記プラグインは作成したjsonファイルからローカライゼーションファイルを生成してくれるものになります。

解決できてないようであれば、お試しください